# Problem creating AVD

Tags: android

I have installed Android SDK on my MAC OS X 10.6 and facing lots of problem while creating AVD.

1. When I tried to create it for ECLIPSE (3.5 Gallelio) then after clicking the 'new' button, when I try to type a name there comes a message bellow saying 'a target must be selected in order to create an AVD'. But the problem is, the Target field is deactivated.
2. If I'm trying to create AVD from terminal with the command './android avd --target 2 --name my_avd' it shows an error saying 'Error: Expected verb after global parameters but found 'avd' instead.'

I don't understand what to do right now. Can anybody help me in this regard please??

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you have to specify the Android SDK installation folder to the Eclipse Android plugin. Go to Preferences -> Android and set it. After that you have to install the target versions you want to develop against.

Go to AVD Manager -> Available Packages and download the targets that you need. After that you should be able to create your AVD. If you still have problems, try restarting Eclipse because that solved some issues for me a number of times.

If you still have problems try reading the [Troubleshooting Tips](http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/troubleshooting.html#eclipse).

Comment: Thanks. I had the same problem and it helped, I also had to go to tools->Options.. and select: Force https sources to be fetched using http

Comment: the [link-Troubleshooting tips](http://developer.android.com/training/faq/troubleshooting.html#eclipse) seems to be broken :)

Answer (score 2):

You have the command line wrong.  You need to add `create` to it.  Try the following:

```
android create avd --target 2 --name my_avd
```